# jQuery not working as expected on page reload

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I have written a jQuery-script, which should run after the page has loaded completely.
It should jump down to the end of the page, hide a div and scroll up with an animation after a little delay.

This is my Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/6utNc/

If I run it from jsFiddle, it works as expected.
If I open it locally in Chrome or Safari (Not tested in FF, Opera and IE) it works as expected too. The problem is, that if I am trying to reload the page, it won't scroll in any way, but runs everything else as expected.

Could the two .scrollTop() kill each other?

```
$('html,body').scrollTop($siteheight);
$('#loader').fadeOut();
$('html,body').delay(2000).animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be silly but I don't see it wrapped in a document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //insert code here
});
```

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6utNc/1/).

Comment: I made the exact same thing...if you reload the frame, it works as expected

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that one! I have forgotten the $ in front of the SIAF. Thanks, that was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of first line:

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.body.clientHeight;
```

and what John Harding mentioned is important too.

Comment: Scrolling down the height of the html tag seems to work fine. Is your code better in performance?

Comment: I don't know really. This is the way to do it in pure javascript but it's a single execution so that might not differ so much i guess.